# Errors in Emacs starting Repl

Tags: emacs, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I use Emacs for Clojure development. When I started Repl by cider-jack-in I got some error, but I can see only a few last lines in echo area. When I click on echo area It says that "Minibuffer window is not active". How can I retrieve the whole error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see all the messages from the echo area in the `*Messages*` buffer.

Comment: How to open that buffer?

Comment: It is one of the 'standard' buffers - use `C-x C-b` to open the buffers list buffer and select it, or just `C-x b` to select it directly.

Comment: Just click `mouse-1` in the echo area (same real estate as the minibuffer).